# How this reading of std::vector works?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I've seen this block of code that is supposed to read a vector in a very strange method to me.

I want to know what does mean:

```
for(auto &it: a) cin >> it;
```

I already know that this for loop iterates trough whole vector, but the part:

```
auto &it
```

and

```
cin >> it;
```

confuses me; because, I'm used to reading vector elements using `push_back()`.

The whole block of code:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
vector<int> a(n);
for (auto &it : a) cin >> it;
```

Comment: The name `it` is misleading, because it is *not* an iterator.

Comment: The thing you are missing is that the for loop in question is operating on a vector that's already sized, and reads one input for each element **already** present in the vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be being tripped up by somebody's poor naming.  The `it` in `for(auto& it:a)` is not an iterator but an element of the vector.

---

## Walking through the program one line at a time

```cpp
int n;
```

Declared a new int to store the size of the vector.

```cpp
cin >> n
```

Gets the size of the vector from the user.

```cpp
vector<int> a(n);
```

Declares a vector of ints with the size `n`. This line makes all of the ints.

```cpp
for (auto& elm : a)
```

For each of those ints we just made, loop though them, naming each `elm` while inside the loop body.

```cpp
cin >> elm;
```

Read in a value from the user and give it's value to the current element in the vector. No int's are made here because they already exists, we just assign to them.